# Dot between every two digits

Tags: php, date

I have a number, for example: `171125` (it's like a date). I want it like `2017.11.25`

I can add this `20` at the beginning like:

```
<span>20 <?php echo $number ?> </span>
```

But what now?

I tried with `number_format` but it's not what I  want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse the date into a `DateTime` object and then easily output it out in the format you want using native `DateTime` functionality:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd', '171125');
echo $date->format('Y.m.d')
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/988586)

Comment: This looks like what i wanted. Thanks

Comment: @Martijn really? How does PHP know it's 2117 and not 2017 the data is from? The `171125` could potentially be 1917 today too, and PHP just assumes it's 2017. Does that make it correct?